# How in JPA create list of pairs as parameter?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

In my Java aplication I want to create SQL query which will in the end will be looking like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.a, t.b) IN ((a1,b1),(a2,b2),(a3,b3), ... )
```

**How to generate it?**

My code looks like this:

```
public List<MyEntity> getMyEntity(List<Long> alist, List<Long> blist) {

    String stringQuery = "SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.a , t.b) in (:alist, :blist)"; 

    // This is kinda how I whould like my query to look, but I guess I will generate something like:
    // SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.a, t.b) IN ((a1, a2, a3, ...), (b1, b2, b3, ...))
    // which isn't the same and it isn't what I want 

    Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(stringQuery, MyEntity.class);

    // I'm using native query because in my aplication above query is in fact much more complicated, 
    // and I can't use standard JPA query. I cut those parts here, because they aren't directly related to my problem
    // in the other way that they force to use native query.

    query.setParameter("alist", alist);
    query.setParameter("blist", blist);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: a native query does not have NAMED parameters. It has positional parameters (if you value portability). Generate your SQL based on how many params there are.

Comment: Then something like this should work `"("+data.stream().map(d -> "("+d.a+","+d.b+")").collect(Collectors.joining(","))+")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a native query, it seem that there is no list parameter at all for native queries:

[Set list parameter to native query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701946/set-list-parameter-to-native-query)

[How to use a dynamic parameter in a IN clause of a JPA named query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484176/how-to-use-a-dynamic-parameter-in-a-in-clause-of-a-jpa-named-query)

You have to concatenate the SQL manually.